# Xcode 4.5 Update (Project Error)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, admob

I updated Xcode and I ran into a project error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/joe/Desktop/AdMob/libGoogleAdMobAds.a for architecture armv7s
```

This worked fine in the older version of Xcode, but not now. I know it has something to do with the file named: libGoogleAdMobAds.a

Which is used for AdMob ads...

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

UPDATE:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are using the latest AdMob SDK for iOS as that error implies the library doesn't have the iOS 6 added architecture (armv7s).

Comment: I just update my question with lots of new Apple-mach link errors

Answer (score 0):

You can select 
project settings->Build-settings->Compiler for C/C++/Objective C
select  Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1
and build the projects